# Read first line of text file then pass following lines to a loop to read

Tags: powershell

I need to read the first line of a file and then the subsequent lines I want read using a loop.

eg:

```
Read in first line
Do stuff with the data

foreach ($line in $remainingLines)
{
    more stuff
}
```

I have a rather messy way to achieve this but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assign the content of the file to two variables. The first one will hold the first line, and the second variable gets the rest. Then loop over $remainingLines.

```
$firstLine,$remainingLines = Get-Content foo.txt
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't seen this before.

Comment: This is how multiple assignment works in PowerShell. If you assign two values, the first parameter gets the first value and so on. But if the values being assigned are greater than the variable count then all remaining values are accumulated in the last variable.

Answer (score 6):

```
$contents = gc .\myfile.txt

write-host $contents[0]

for ($i=1; $i -lt $contents.Length; $i++)
{
  write-host $contents[$i]
}
```